# Особенности работы циклов и итераторов в python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть метод, написанный на python 2.7:

```
def findKeyInFnames(listOfDicts, someValue):
    for element in listOfDicts:
        if(element['someKey']==someValue):
            return element['someOtherKey']
        else:
            return 'Not found'
```

- `ListOfDicts` - список однотипных словарей с некоторыми значениями
- `someValue` - некоторое значение ключа, по которому происходит поиск

При каждом вызове метод должен возвращать значение с другим ключом из того же словаря.

Проблема в том, что вне зависимости от значений ключей и их совпадения возвращается всегда `"Not found"`. При этом, если сделать вот так:

```
def findKeyInFnames(listOfDicts, someValue):
    for element in listOfDicts:
        if(element['someKey']==someValue):
            return element['someOtherKey']
```

то всё работает как надо и нужные значения возвращаются, за исключением того, что вместо `not found` возвращается `None`.

Почему так происходит и как вместо `None` возвращать из метода свое сообщение?

Comment: Ну так у вас же в коде и написано при первом же несовпадении возвращать Not found — как написано, так питон себя и ведёт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return 'Not found'
```

разместите не в цикле, а последней строчкой процедуры.

```
def findKeyInFnames(listOfDicts, someValue):
    for element in listOfDicts:
        if(element['someKey']==someValue):
            return element['someOtherKey']
    return 'Not found'
```

Comment: точно, спасибо большое! не понял сразу в чем проблема, нужен был взгляд со стороны

Answer (score 0):

```
def findKeyInFnames(listOfDicts, someValue):
    for element in listOfDicts:
        if(element['someKey']==someValue):
            return element['someOtherKey']
    else:
        return 'Not found'
```

Comment: Если бы выход из цикла был по `break`, а не через `return`, то в `else` был бы смысл, а так `else` совсем не обязательно.